# checkout/session not returning order id while it is working on development site

Tags: magento, checkout

I am working with magento and third party payment wallet Mobikwik. I got it working in my development site. But same code in production site does not return success page but return shopping cart empty after payment.

Path of file : `community/wallet/controllers/Transactcontroller.php`

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
    $session->setQuoteId($session->getWalletQuoteId(true));
    $walletConfig = Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/wallet');

    $statuscode = $postdata['statuscode'];
    $orderid = $postdata['orderid'];
    $mid = $postdata['mid'];
    $amount = $postdata['amount'];
    $message = $postdata['statusmessage'];
    $checksumReceived = $postdata['checksum'];

    $all = "'" . $statuscode . "''" . $orderid . "''" . $amount . "''" . $message . "''" . $mid . "'";

    if($checksumReceived != null){
        $isChecksumValid = $this -> verifyChecksum($checksumReceived, $walletConfig['secret_key'], $all);
    }

    if($isChecksumValid){
        // success
        if ($this->_validateResponse()) {

            Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->setIsActive(false)->save();
            $order2 = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($session->getLastRealOrderId());
            $order1 = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($postdata['orderid']);
            $total_amount = (double)$order2->getGrandTotal();  //// total amount from database for an order ////            

            if( ((double)$postdata['amount'] == (double)$order2->getGrandTotal()) AND ($session->getLastRealOrderId() == $postdata['orderid'])) { 
   // success code here and redirect to success page
     else { // print error message }
```

`$order2` is returning nothing but `$order1` returning correct values.

**Above code is working in development site**. I found that problem is in production database.
Can anyone point me any correct direction!